# Increasing size of button every time it is pressed on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I would like to know how to increase the size of a button every time it is pressed. I'm trying to make a simple game where 2 players using 1 phone press on their button located on opposite sides of the screen. Their button gets bigger the more it is clicked, causing the other players button to decrease in size. I have both buttons taking half the screen right now, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to increase the size of a button as it is clicked.

Comment: `I'm having difficulty` Please show your attempt ([edit] your question).

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the storyboard, connect the width and height constraints to your code. Then when your button is pressed, increase it.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    widthConstraint.constant += 10
    heightConstraint.constant += 10
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: This will not work if you don't call a `layoutIfNeeded()` after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the frame of your button bigger, each time it is tapped.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let button = sender as! UIButton
            //change the frame every time it is tapped
            let increaseValue : CGFloat = 5.0
            let newFrame = CGRectMake(b.frame.origin.x, b.frame.origin.y, b.frame.size.width + increaseValue, b.frame.size.width + increaseValue)
            b.frame = frame
            self.view.layoutSubviews() //update the button frame
     }
```

Comment: This would not work if he has constrained the button's width and height.

Comment: He didn't say that its button has constraints.